# Modelling a GI/G/1 queue with exceptional first vacation and multiple vacations

Tags: pr.probability

I am currently working on a stochastic modelling problem in networks. I have a G/G/1 queue where

- the interarrival and inter-service times are iid
- the arrival and service time distributions are independent of one another
- whenever the server is idle, it starts a vacation. When it returns from a vacation and finds the system empty, it commences another vacation and so on.
- there is an exceptional first random variable wrt the vacation process, i.e., at the end of every busy period, $V_1$, the RV for which the server goes on vacation differs in distribution from $V_2$, $V_3,\ldots$

I work towards getting basic system quantities like average waiting time of a customer and expected number of customers at any instant of time.

I came across this paper by [Doshi] (www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/3213784), which provides a stochastic decomposition for the equilibrium waiting time. But this is only for provides a way to compute delay for iid $V_i$s and I am interested in its extensions and alternate solutions. I checked its citations but could not zero in on any paper for the same problem.

### Non-stationary arrivals and exceptional first vacation time

Specifically I aim for the following improvements to suit my problem.

- How do the results change for exceptional first time vacation?
- How do I extend the problem to non-stationary arrival process? Are there papers that reliably approximate non-stationary processes as GI processes? Is there any other way?

### Extending instantaneous pinging of the queue

In most queues solved in papers, there is only a point-pinging of the system. That is, the server wakes up after a vacation, sees the system at one instant and then makes a decision whether or not to take another vacation. In my case, the server waits for a deterministic duration before its next vacation.

- How do I extend the multiple vacations model for the case of finite time observation of the channel?